# Angular google maps - View directions link is taking time to update origin & destination

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, map-directions

[image]I have the below code to capture the origin and destination on click of view directions button. The problem is on click of view directions button, the href URL loads first before the onclick event completes its execution. How to load the href URL after the execution of function passed to click event. In the below code , I am capturing the lat and lng of origin and destination in getDirection method and once the values are available only , the external href url should be loaded. But in my case, for the first time click , since the values of origin and destination are not available the URL has empty value, whereas from the second click onwards , the values are available .

```
   <a (click)="getDirection(m.geometry.location.lat,m.geometry.location.lng)" href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin={{srcOriginLat}},{{srcOriginLng}}&destination={{srcDestinationLat}},{{srcDestinationLng}}&travelmode=driving" target='_blank'>Directions</a></button>


getDirection(dirLat: any, dirLng: any) {
    let srcLat, srcLng;
    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {

      srcLat = position.coords.latitude;
      srcLng = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log('srcLatsrcLng1', srcLat, srcLng);
      this.dir = {
        origin: { latitude: srcLat, longitude: srcLng },
        destination: { latitude: dirLat, longitude: dirLng }
      };
         this.srcOriginLat = this.dir.origin.latitude;
      this.srcOriginLng = this.dir.origin.longitude;
      this.srcDestinationLat = this.dir.destination.latitude;
      this.srcDestinationLng = this.dir.destination.longitude;
      });
    }

  }
```

Comment: Have you thought about using AGM? This is a angular google maps for angular applications. Is very easy to use. You won't need a href

Comment: Yes i am using AGM . agm-marker and info window everything works fine. But my question is regarding how to execute the click event first and after the click event completes , i need to open the href. Basically my question has nothing to do with agm in specific.

Comment: You are right I misunderstood your question.  I think you can try something like this insdie your getDirections()... add this line : `window.open(https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin={{srcOriginLat}},{{srcOriginLng}}&destination={{srcDestinationLat}},{{srcDestinationLng}}&travelmode=driving" target='_blank');`  and you can changed this to an `<button>` instead of a `<a>`if this doesn't work add a stackbliz so I can assist you better .

Comment: I already tried with window.open('https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin={{srcOriginLat}},{{srcOriginLng}}&destination={{srcDestinationLat}},{{srcDestinationLng}}&travelmode=driving', '_blank');
The problem is the parameters passed in {{}} doesnt take its values. Attached the screenshot.

Comment: @PatricioVargas any idea on how to set timedelay for href . I basically want the click method to complete its execution and then execute href. How to achieve this?

Comment: the problem is that it's a callback so you have to wait for the callback to come back. DO NOT use any setTime or delay or anything like that. Than's bad practice. you can use .then() but let me see if I find a better solution by trying to replicate your problem. If you make a stackbliz that would be great

Comment: Ok let me try to create stackblitz, but mean while in case if you have any solutions, that will be great